# Why aren't all modules pre-imported?

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, automation, manual

I have started learning coding recently... and I often have to import modules like import random, import os, import turtle etc(in python). Why does this process have to me manual? Why aren't all these modules pre imported?

Comment: This is not the place for these kinds of questions, but, since you asked, it ensures that the program only loads what it needs. Also, you can define your own modules, and use other peoples' modules.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't all preimported because it would need much memory and it's more efficient if you just load what you really need